# wordpress - how let users add location on a map?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I'm using Wordpress to build my website, i want to add a form that will have: name, description, image and **location on a map**. that is letting the users add their own marker on a map.

and by pressing 'submit' the whole data (name, description, image, longitude, latitude) would be saved to a database.

how can i do that? which plugins should i use?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Google Placemarks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/basic-google-maps-placemarks/) and give them access to the creation of the 'Placemarks' custom post type that plugin utilises. You might have to hack the featured image..

Alternatively, you're looking at full custom post type creation and google maps API integration, a custom loop that utilises of the featured image.

Answer (score 2):

Plugin that comes closest to what you need is what SMacFadyen suggested - [BGMP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/basic-google-maps-placemarks/). But if you want to do that yourself you would need to look into this:

- [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)
- [WordPress Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)
- WordPress Meta Boxes

For the first one there is lots of tutorials on how to display map and InfoWindows so you shouldn't have much problem with that. For Custom Post Types there is an awesome [generator](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/) which should do 99% of your work. For Meta Boxes you can go several ways:

- [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-box/) - easiest but you would depend on a plugin which I don't like very much
- from scratch - [tutorial](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) - which is a lot better than plugin but requires a lot of work
- one of the meta box libraries - this is the way I usually go - I'm developing my own but it's not ready yet so in the mean time I would recommend [My-Meta-Box](https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box) or [Reusable Custom WordPress Meta Boxes](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes)

Comment: tnx for the reply, for the form i'm using 'Contact Form 7' with 'Contact Form 7 to Database Extension'. is there a way to hook the marker feature inside those plugins?

Comment: God knows. As I said - I tend not to rely on other peoples plugins :)

Answer (score 1):

Several times, when searching how to make this work, I stumbled upon this thread. Every time, I wasn't really happy with the way existing plugins deal with this. So, I now put this together myself.

Here's an overview of my solution.

1. Use the plugin [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to create a custom post type for the markers on the map.
2. Use the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to add a field to this custom post type which represents the location. The field type is of type 'Google Map'.
3. Copy the standard [Google Maps API clustering example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) to the appropriate theme file in your theme.
4. For showing your markers, generate the list of locations by, in your theme file, requesting the posts of your newly created custom post type.
5. For each marker/location, pick up the 'Google Map' field and abstract the latitude and longitude.
6. For each marker/location, construct the appropriate array element for the array with all locations, with, at least, the latitude and the longitude, and probably also the contents of an infowindow.

This should give you a map with all locations plotted out.

To allow users to add locations:

1. Add a listener to your map that listens for clicks and returns the location clicked. Perhaps this listener is only running after the user has expressed his intent to add a location to the map.
2. When the user has clicked, open a form, for example in a modal. The form should contain hidden fields with the latitude and longitude and could, for example, also contain a static image of the relevant location. Other form fields would be the fields you need for your purpose.
3. Submit the form using AJAX. Refer, for example, to [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/). In your theme's functions.php, you can then validate the submission and add the new submission to your Wordpress database, matching your new custom post type.

Depending on how you store your new location, on your next map reload, the new location will be included. (Or you perhaps need to authorise the new location, first.)
You can also reload all locations through AJAX.

Comment: I have been trying to do something similar to this, but I'm a beginner with wordpress, and I'm not sure I understand all of what you describe. If you are still listening and if you have the time, I would be really grateful for a more detailed explanation of bullet 4. Maybe even a snippet of code showing how to do that.

Comment: Hi @plithner. At this point, I don't have the code too easily accessible, but this is not that complex. The easiest (but not the most robust), is to just use wp_query to return all posts of the post-type in question.

Answer (score -1):

[Profile Builder](https://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/) allows you to do just that. Create a front-end register form including the required custom fields and a map field for users to pin or enter their location.

Then using the built-in User Listing (Member Directory) module, you can display a [map of all users](https://www.cozmoslabs.com/160142-add-users-map-wordpress/) locations.